# get itemCount from a list

Tags: list, flutter, listview, dart

I have this `json` structure

```
  "abc":{
        current_checklist:[
        {
         .... 
        },
        {
          "sections":[
              ...
           ]
        },
        {
             ...         
        }
     ]
  }
```

I want to use `ListView`, where the `itemCount` is based on sections. How should I write it?

```
Widget _displayCheckList(ABCData abcData) {
    return ListView.builder(
      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemCount:
          abcData.abc.currentChecklist.???,length,  // how to get the "sections" length? 
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return Text("Hello");
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Are the `sections` available only in one of the objects of `current_checklist` or it is available in all of them?

Comment: @RaviSinghLodhi all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would have been good to see some valid sample json data.

Did you try something like :

```
abcData.abc.currentChecklist[0].sections or
abcData.abc.currentChecklist[1].sections
```